# Unable to allocate memory inside a function and return it in C

Tags: c, memory, segmentation-fault, malloc, pointer-to-pointer

I want to allocate some memory to a pointer using a function. Following is the code I have written:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int test( unsigned char **q)
{
    *q = (unsigned char *) malloc(250);
    if(*q == NULL)
    {
        printf("\n Error: failed to allocate memory");
        return -1;
    }   
//  *q[0] = 10;
//  *q[1] = 10;
    *q[2] = 10;

    return 0;   /* Returns 0 on success, non-zero value on failure */
}

int main(void)
{
    unsigned char *p;

//  printf("\n &p = %u", &p);
    int result = test(&p);  

//  printf("\n p[2] = %d", p[2]);
    return 0;
}
```

If I write something in `*q[0]` or `*q[1]`, there is no error. But when I try to write something to `*q[2]`, it gives "Segmentation fault (core dumped)".

Also I'm getting all data as 0 using `p[ ]` except `p[0]`.

What is wrong with this code?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [Please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917).

Comment: `*q[2] = 10;` should be `(*q)[2] = 10;`.

Comment: Lack of knowledge != Typo. Voting to Reopen. Feel free to close as dupe.

Comment: Yes.. this was a mistake due to ignorance. Also this was the first time I dealt with memory allocation inside the function and returning it. Thanks for instant answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of this wrong assignment

```
*q[2] = 10;
```

that is due to the operator precedence equivalent to

```
*( q[2] ) = 10;
```

and as result the dereferenced pointer q[2] is uninitialized and has indeterminate value. You should write either like

```
( *q )[2] = 10;
```

or even just like

```
q[0][2] = 10;
```

Another way is to introduce an intermediate variable and use it to initialize elements of the array. For example

```
char *p = *q;

p[2] = 10;
```

This allows to escape that kind of errors with pointers.

Comment: And don't make mistake of adding intermediate variable p before allocating memory.

Answer (score 2):

Due to the absense of explicit parenthesis and thus, default [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) coming into effect, your expression is interpreted wrongly.

For an expression like

```
 *q[2]
```

it is interpreted as

```
*(q[2])
```

which is what you don't want here. Pointer arithmetic honors the data type, so, `x + 1` or `x[1]` will have **different** results, when

- `x` is type `char *`
- `x` is of type `char **`.

You need to write

```
 (*q)[2] = 10;
```

explicitly, first to dereference the `q` to get the `char *`, and then , use the indexing to get the char.

Answer (score 2):

Due to operator precedence of C language, for `*q[2]`, `[]` operator is evaluated before `*` operator.

So `*q[2]` is the value at address `q + 2`. What you want is value at `*q + 2`. So use `(*q) + 2`.

`*q[0]` or `*q[1]` did not give segmentation fault because addresses `q + 0`, `q + 1` have been allocated to your process.

Address `q + 2` was not allocated to your process and hence the segmentation fault.

Comment: Thanks. Your answer explains reasoning for all the errors I got. Vlad from Moscow gave different ways to avoid these errors. So I accepted that answer.